Google Web <-> Mobile Flow with Spring Boot Backend
I'm a bit struggling with the following scenario:
Integrated Google flow with a web-app (VUE) and Spring Boot Backend (user logs in to google on web, web sends authCode, all other requests are being done on backend [fetching calendar etc.])
Everything works GREAT, no problemo, using GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow from com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.
Now, I want to do the same thing on Mobile (both iOS and Android).
From what I understood, this requires separate Client IDs from separate apps in the Google Dev Console. (please correct me if I'm wrong in this)
But then how exactly would this work with integration in the backend? Am I working with a wrong assumption (different clients?) Should mobile actually work everything through a webview instead of having separate clientids? I'm a bit lost here...

I don't think you need different client ids for Vue.js and mobile apps. You can use the same client for both mobile and web if that client is public. Oauth2 supports 2 types of client: public and confidential. A frontend client such as a mobile app must be public as it cannot store securely a client secret, used to authenticate the client app with the oauth2 provider (in your case Google).
Once you obtain a token in your frontend app, you has to validate it on the backend using spring-oauth library.


Am I working with a wrong assumption (different clients?)

Yes, probably, but that depends on what you configure as the OAuth2 client(s):

If configuring the frontends (Vue, Android, and iOS), you should use public client(s) (no secret). You may use different clients, but this doesn't bring much value. In this situation, the tokens are delivered to the apps on the end-user device which may query the Google APIs directly or share the access token with the backend for it to call the Google APIs.
If you configure the Spring backend as an OAuth2 client, you have a single confidential client (which uses a secret to call the Google token endpoint). Tokens are delivered to the backend and only it should query the Google APIs.

Using public clients (even with PKCE) and exposing access tokens to the user device (and dependencies code) can save server resources and reduce latency (if calling Google APIs directly from the user device), but it is now considered unsafe.
You may use no more than spring-boot-starter-ouath2-client to achieve the second option (no need for Google dependencies).
Be aware that requests sent to Spring clients with oauth2Login are authorized with a session cookie, which requires:

protection against CSRF (cookie-based in case of single-page & mobile applications)
some support for cookies and to set the X-XSRF-TOKEN header: the HTTP clients used in mobile apps usually don't handle cookies transparently as browsers do, and neither Vue nor mobile HTTP clients handle the CSRF token for you (like Angular does for instance)

I detailed what it takes to authorize a mobile application against an OAuth2 backend configured with the authorization code flow in this other answer.
You can find a sample of setting the X-XSRF-TOKEN header for a POST request in a Vue application in the logout section of this Baeldung article I wrote. All - and only - POST, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE requests to your backend should have this header set.

Thank you for the writeup. The clients (both, web and mobile) authenticate on their own with Google's AUTH flow and obtain a token which is then shared with backend that does the actual calls to the necessary Google APIs

@Alexandr PKCE protects with CSRF attacks. On the client side, you should ensure that PKCE is used. Using Google's SDK (or other vendor SDKs) on the client may already do this. It might even be a requirement on the authorisation server (and it is with OAuth2.1). In addition to this, on mobile devices, the communication between the browser (running the authentication and authorisation) and the app can be a secure channel already (receiving the code), when it  does use special system features. On iOS this is the ASWebAuthenticationSession from the AuthenticationServices framework, for example.

@CouchDeveloper PKCE protects against CSRF only during the authorization code flow, not for requests to the REST API. Exchanging the code between the browser and an app is a thing, but what I refer to in the linked answer is the session cookie (and a browser shouldn't share that).

@Alexandr as already wrote in my answer, according to latest security experts recommendations, what you call clients - and I call frontends - shouldn't be OAuth2 clients. This requires using public clients (without a secret), and more importantly, exposing tokens to frontends code also exposes it to frontend dependencies code. If only one of these many dependencies is compromised, tokens might be exfiltered. Also, if you accept that risk, you should consider making Google API calls from the frontend instead, and send to the backend only what really needs to be persisted on your side.

@ch4mp I was actually referring only to the authorisation flow, up to the point where the app receives the authorisation credentials. But when considering CSRF attacks, native apps don't use a web browser to access the resource server. You made some interesting points about security of the authorisation credentials. Here, we can only try to trust the developers ;)  A native client can store the credentials in its secure store, and system browsers would do the same. However, this doesn't prevent the app developer to share the credentials with anyone.

The BFF serves a Vue application => it must be protected against CSRF for all the requests changing the backend state (not just login). The mobile apps consume the same BFF => it must provide the CSRF token as X-XSRF-TOKEN with POST, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE requests too. And no, we can't trust all the developers of a Javascript application's transient dependencies. Session cookies are not exposed to Javascript, that's why it should be preferred to Bearer tokens.
